# How do you retrieve the image source of an image that the user has clicked on? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve the image source of an image that the user has clicked on.
This is what I have and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var imgSrc = getSrc(image)

    function getSrc(image) {
        $('img').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                $(this).attr('src')
            }); //end click
        }); //end each  
    } //end getSrc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('img').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).attr('src') ); // or this.src
 });
```

You don't need any loop. Above code will work just fine, I think.

**Full code**

```
function getSrc(image) {
   var src;
   $('img').click(function() {
     src = $(this).attr('src'); // or this.src
   }); 
   return src;
}
```

#### Note

In your question you don't use `image` arguments in code. I'm not sure why you're using this. If you want to use get `src` of that `image` you passed via arguments then you can try:

```
$(image).attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the function.  Also, you do not need the .each() call as you know the image that has been clicked:

```
var imgSrc = '';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function () {
        imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    });
});
```